# Connect to raspberry pi (non public ip via 4G/LTE) from an android phone (non puplic ip via 4G/LTE)

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, tunnel, mobile-broadband

I have a raspberry pi running mariadb connected to a 4G/LTE router.

I want to connect to mariadb from an android phone on 4G/LTE.

As i only have a non puplic IPv4 IP Adress on the 4G/LTE router, i cannot just use the port forwarding on the router.

Any ideas?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You need like amazon aws or some cloud computing act so that they both make outbound connections to that.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Can you recommend any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect directly, you need some kind of reflector (with public IP) that receives the connections from the android phone and forwards them to the raspberry (that has to keep an open connection to the reflector in order to "punch" its NAT).